# Tkinter marked Checkbutton as check due to config values

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter

hi i am using a loop to create 10 checkbuttons, but only the last button check the value from config, in another 9 `value` was set to `1` but they still unmark.

```
for j in range(len(self.config['Currency'])):
        self.currency_value = IntVar(value=self.config_values[j])
        self.currency_button = Checkbutton(self.top, text=self.currency_tags[j].upper(), variable=self.currency_value)
        if j < 5:
            row_n = 1
            col_n = j
        else:
            row_n = 2
            col_n = j - 5
        self.currency_button.grid(row=row_n, column=col_n, pady=8)
```

thx for help

Comment: create your checkbuttons in a list. You can manage the widgets a bit easier this way.

Comment: Are you using ttk checkbuttons or tkinter checkbuttons?

Comment: tkinter  checkbuttons

Comment: create a list of `IntVar` and then take from list by index. Cause now there is a list of values from config file `1 and 0`

Comment: thx for help list of `IntVar`s work great

Answer (score 0):

The best wat is to create list of checkbuuttuns as  Sierra Mountain Tech said